# What is a canonical safe way of async lazy initialization in javascript?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, eslint

I have this sort of lazy initialization code in my program:

```
let user = null;        
let getUser = async () => {
  if(!user) {
    user = await getUserSomehow();
  }
  return user;
};
```

I understand that it is not safe, due to a possible race condition if I have the next code:

```
// one place of the program
let u1 = await getUser();
...
// another place of the program running during getUserSomehow() for u1 still hasn't finished
let u2 = await getUser();
```

`getUserSomehow()` will be called two times instead of one.

How to avoid this situation?

Comment: Just drop the `await`.

Comment: @Bergi your comment is so short that at first glance it looks stupid (like you are advising to get rid of async code). However, if it's not planned to use "user" variable directly anywhere, you are completely right.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When called for the first time, assign a Promise instead, and on further calls, return that Promise:

```
let userProm = null;
let getUser = () => {
  if (!userProm) {
    userProm = getUserSomehow();
  }
  return userProm;
};
```

Even better, scope `userProm` only inside `getUser`, to be safer and clear:

```
const getUser = (() => {
  let userProm = null;
  return () => {
    if (!userProm) {
      userProm = getUserSomehow();
    }
    return userProm;
  };
})();
```

```js
const getUserSomehow = () => {
  console.log('getting user');
  return Promise.resolve('data');
};

const getUser = (() => {
  let userProm = null;
  return () => {
    if (!userProm) {
      userProm = getUserSomehow();
    }
    return userProm;
  };
})();

(async () => {
  const userProm1 = getUser();
  const userProm2 = getUser();
  Promise.all([userProm1, userProm2]).then(() => {
    console.log('All done');
  });
})();
```

Your existing code *happens* to be safe, because the assignment to `user` will occur before the first call of `getUser` finishes:

```js
const getUserSomehow = () => {
  console.log('Getting user');
  return Promise.resolve('data');
};

let user = null;
let getUser = async() => {
  if (!user) {
    user = await getUserSomehow();
  }
  return user;
};

(async () => {
  let u1 = await getUser();
  let u2 = await getUser();
  console.log('Done');
})();
```

But it wouldn't be if the Promises were initialized in parallel, before one of them was `await`ed to completion first:

```js
const getUserSomehow = () => {
  console.log('Getting user');
  return Promise.resolve('data');
};

let user = null;
let getUser = async() => {
  if (!user) {
    user = await getUserSomehow();
  }
  return user;
};

(async() => {
  let u1Prom = getUser();
  let u2Prom = getUser();
  await Promise.all([u1Prom, u2Prom]);
  console.log('Done');
})();
```

As shown above, assigning the Promise to the persistent variable (instead of `await`ing the value inside `getUser`) fixes this.

Comment: Thank you for the several examples providing better understanding! You are right that in my original post I have had a wrong example about getting the race condition.

Comment: Very nicely answered.  I'm surprised this issue doesn't come up more frequently.  Another practice I follow is to keep my promise references at the top of the module (so I can keep track of them) and implement a "getter" and "resetter" for each.  A disadvantage of the inner scope is: no ability to write that "resetter."